# 16.04: Cannot uninstall dwm

Tags: apt, package-management, 16.04, uninstall, window-manager

I install dwm via apt, and I want to remove it and build it from source. Problem is I can't get rid of it! I've done

```
sudo apt-get remove dwm
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove dwm
sudo apt-get purge dwm
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove dwm
```

it just keeps telling me that dwm is not installed. If I do `locate dwm` all that comes up is some dwmac stuff, yet I can still run dwm as my window manager when I log in.

Answer (score 0):

Installing from the repositories isn't very useful since you can't configure it. However, it is convenient to install with `apt-get` so that, when building from source, it is added to the options in the login screen. You don't need to uninstall it to install from source.

Source and further instructions: https://cannibalcandy.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/installing-and-configuring-dwm-under-ubuntu/

Comment: I did not actually need to entirely remove the program, I just had to download and recompile the source. The OS seems to have done most of the work.